# Permission documents within library so only initiator and approver (varying) can see it

Tags: permissions, approval-process, content-approval

I am trying to build out a performance review site and need to allow reviewee (document originator) and approver the ability to see document (no one else).

I need for the reviewee to upload their document and then tag document with approver (via people picker-AD).

How can I get the approver to be able to see the document.  I'll have many different approvers (and will vary from project to project) so there's no way I can fine grain permission.  I currently have content approval turned.

Answer (score 1):

One of possible ways to implement this:

1. Add a `User or Group` field named "Approved by", make it required
2. Whoever uploads a document fills that field selecting user from people picker
3. Create a workflow named "Access restriction" that starts automatically on item creation
4. Inside that workflow: first break role inheritance on the item, then add `item["Author"]` with `Read` level, `item["Approved_by"]` with `Read` level and supervisors, then implement approval process with tasks, emails and other stuff, after approval is over you should restore role inheritance or add `Site Users` with whatever access needed

All this can be done in SPD (see [sample for the first part](http://spcycle.blogspot.com/2012/01/how-to-create-workflow-to-change-item.html))

Comment: YEAH!!  Works like a charm!  Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Sure, welcome to SPSO. Bonus: custom activity for breaking role inheritance in SharePoint Designer 2013 - https://sp2013workflowactivities.codeplex.com/

Comment: @Darcie by the way, please consider marking this as answer so that anyone in future knows how you met your requirement